# Insert User in localhost in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am creating databases in MySQL and PostgreSQL. When I am going to create a user that only can work in localhost (like MySQL with: `create user 'X'@'localhost'`), I can't do it. Is there any way to create the equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look for pg_hba.conf file - you can define user access there

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html